# Distribution of $X_1X_2X_3$ if $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ has PDF $\frac{2}{2e-5}x_1^2x_2e^{x_1x_2x_3}$ on $0< x_1,x_2,x_3<1$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The random vector **X** = $(X_1,X_2,X_3)'$ has density function

$f_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{2e-5}.x_1^2.x_2.e^{x_1.x_2.x_3}, & for & 0  < x_1,x_2,x_3<1 \\[2ex]
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Determine the distribution of $X_1.X_2.X_3$:

I've tried getting the marginals and multiply them to get the pdf of

$Y=X_1.X_2.X_3$

but I'm not sure if that could be done since I'm not sure if I can assume that $X_i$'s are all independent.

My main issue is with the bounds with min. I can't figure those out.

Comment: They are not independent.  Even if they were, multiplying the marginal densities would not give you the density of the product

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we write the CDF of $Y=X_1X_2X_3$, $F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)$ when $0\leq y \leq 1$:
$$F_Y(y)=\int_0^{1}\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mathbf{I}(x_1x_2x_3\leq y)dx_1dx_2dx_3$$

This can be written in three regions: (simplify the notation as $f(\mathbf{x})$ and $d\mathbf{x}$ to denote $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $dx_1dx_2dx_3$, in the same order.
$$F_Y(y)=\int_0^y\int_0^1\int_0^1f(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}+\int_y^1\int_0^{y/x_1}\int_0^1f(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}+\int_y^1\int_{y/x_1}^1\int_0^{y/x_1x_2}f(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}$$
Performing the integrations, if I don't have any computational mistakes, this CDF can be found as
$$F_Y(y)=\frac{e^y(y^2-4y+5)-5}{2e-5}$$
which yields (for $0\leq y \leq 1$)
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{dF_Y(y)}{dy}=\frac{e^y(y-1)^2}{2e-5}$$

Comment: my main issue is with the bounds that you have with min. I can't figure those out

Comment: like going from the first line to the second

Comment: I actually went from second to first :) while trying to represent it more compact, introduced a mistake. Now edited. However, the second integral is correct. Do you have problems with it?

Comment: I now have a problem with the $F_Y(y)=\int_0^y\int_0^1\int_0^1f(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}+\int_y^1\int_0^{y/x_1}\int_0^1f(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}+\int_y^1\int_{y/x_1}^1\int_0^{y/x_1x_2}f(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}$

Comment: I mean I can take it as it is but if I get a question on the bounds I won't be able to explain it

Comment: The first integral: When $x_1<y$, $x_2,x_3$ can be anything in $[0,1]$, still $x_1x_2x_3<y$. When $x_1>y$, there are two options. Second integral: If $x_2<y/x_1$, $x_3$ can be anything since $x_1x_2<y$. Third integral: When $x_2>y/x_1$, $x_1x_2$ becomes $>y$, and we need to consider $x_3$ 's where $x_1x_2x_3<y$. To be able to do that, we need to choose $x_3<y/x_1x_2$.

Comment: got it thank you !